# how to change format of ent file into PDB format?

Tags: molecular-biology, bioinformatics, database

whenever i download files from Protein Data Bank(PDB),they are downloaded in .ent format. How can i convert them into PDB format??

Answer (score 4):

Just rename the file to .pdb - in other words, .ent files *are* PDB format:

> The archival PDB files will be distributed with the reserved conventional names, in the form pdbentry_id.ent, where entry_id is a PDB 4-letter code, e.g. pdb1abc.ent, for PDB format entries; rentry_idsf.ent, e.g. r1abcsf.ent, for X-ray experimental data; entry_id.mr, e.g. 1abc.mr, for NMR experimental/constraints; entry_id.cif, e.g. 1abc.cif, for mmCIF format entries; and entry_id.xml, e.g. 1abc.xml, for canonical XML format entries.

From http://www.wwpdb.org/about/faq

Comment: nothing happened..:/ still it's a ENT file

Comment: Not sure what you mean, sorry. If you open it in a text editor you should see that it looks the same (I think). I can't seem to access the pdb's ftp server at the moment, sadly.

Comment: @HayaDar Open the file fresh in notepad, file > Save As > **file types: all files** and change the whole thing to filename.pdb